# React.js Object fetched into Context from Firestore is undefined, when using it in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am facing a problem, as I am trying to use variable, which is being fetched in Context. And it's not a first time I had this problem, so seems like I am missing some crucial concept in React.

In my Context I am fetching object from firestore and setting it as a state. I worked with this fetched object before, so I know that problem is not in fetching or object structure.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCategoriesMap = async () => {
      const categoryMap = await getCategoriesAndDocuments('categories')
      const all = await Object.values(categoryMap).reduce((acc, arr) => acc.concat(arr), [])
      setProducts({ all, ...categoryMap }) 
    }
    getCategoriesMap()
    setFilteredProducts(products['all'])
  }, [])
```

But as I am trying to use state with this object in another component - I get error 'Cannot read properties of undefined'.

For example here:

```
const { products } = useContext(ProductsContext)
const newCollection = products?.all?.filter(product => product.new === true)
```

Or here:

```
const maxSteps = newCollection?.length

return (
    <div className='new-img' style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${newCollection[activeStep]?.imgUrl})` }}></div>
  )
```

Could somebody tell me the reason why the state is undefined, or even better provide with some useful links to read on this topic.

Comment: Do you have `<ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products }}>` anywhere? Are you able to use products anywhere else? If you console out products after the useContext, what does it say?

Comment: Yes, I have ```export const ProductsContext = createContext({ products: [], setProducts: () => {}, filteredProducts: [], setFilteredProducts: () => {},})``` and ```<ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products,  setProducts, filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts }}>```. Right now this bug fully breaks my web-app, so I can't see if I can use it elsewhere. I get empty array from products (initial value) and I cannot understand why I get it instead of my fetched object.

Comment: It looks like code is trying to use state, before it has been set through fetching from firestore in Context. And that is why I get undefined.